# Unable to get full webpage source with Jsoup

Tags: jsoup

I used the Jsoup library to get the source code of this webpage:

url="http://ww3.365planetwinall.net/Sport/OddsAsync.aspx?EventID=257612"

I used the code below, but the returned source code is missing lot of divs. I tried without userAgent, but I get the same thing.

```
doc =Jsoup.connect("http://ww3.365planetwinall.net/Sport/OddsAsync.aspx?EventID=257612")
  .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
  .referrer("http://www.google.com")
  .get();
       String html=doc.toString();

           System.out.println(html);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely the URL you are trying to access renders its content via JavaScript. Jsoup can't deal with that, so you are out of luck. I see two options for you:

1. Use [selenium webdriver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) instead of Jsoup. This remote controls a real browser which can run JavaScript and render all page content as you would expect it. This solution is quite slow, but it gets you there.
2. Identify the AJAX calls this page does via the Browser Network tab and load these resources directly via Jsoup. Often the content is not HTML but JSON or even some other format. You need to spend some time understanding what is going on, but as a reward you still can use Jsoup to get the pages which should be much faster than selenium.